# React.js - data output after clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good evening everyone.

We have an ATM' screen which is React.js component (e.g. "screen.jsx").

Client inputs money and wants to know comission for this operation.

We have the formula for comission calculation:

**(this.props.comission * this.state.summ).toFixed(2)**

This is the task:

After clicking the button "comission calculation" the result of calculation must appear in span near "Comission amount".[image]

Please tell me how to realize this process in JavaScript

Thank you

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: "Please tell me how to realize this process in JavaScript"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the comission amount a property of the state of your Screen component.

```
this.state = {
  comissionAmount: 0
}
```

When you calculate the comission amount when the button is clicked, set `this.state.comissionAmount` to the value you obtained.

```
let comissionAmount = (this.props.comission * this.state.summ).toFixed(2);

this.setState({
  comissionAmount: comissionAmount
});
```

Bind the `<span>` content to be that of `this.state.comissionAmount`.

```
<span>{this.state.comissionAmount}</span>
```